# CSS two columns without specific widths

Tags: css, layout, css-float

I am trying to port a simple two column table to use div and float. I need the feature of a table that is able to scale the width of all columns to the largest content (without taking the whole browser width), but would like the added feature of floats to be able to split the columns when the browser width is reduced.

[image]

I can achieve this using something like this:

```css
div {
  max-width: 285px;
}

div div:first-child {
  float: left;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  margin: 1px;
  width: 145px;
}

div div:nth-of-type(2) {
  float: right;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  margin: 1px;
  width: 130px;
}

div div:last-child {
  clear: left;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <div>The</div>
  <div>12</div>
  <div class="clear" />
  <div>The cat</div>
  <div>12 34</div>
  <div class="clear" />
  <div>The cat sat</div>
  <div>12 34 56</div>
  <div class="clear" />
  <div>The cat sat on</div>
  <div>12 34 56 78</div>
  <div class="clear" />
  <div>The cat sat on the</div>
  <div>12 34 56 78 9A</div>
  <div class="clear" />
  <div>The cat sat on the mat</div>
  <div>12 34 56 78 9A BC</div>
  <div class="clear" />
</div>
```

How is it possible to achieve the same result without needing to set `width` and `max-width` values for the divs?  With a table this would be automatic, but would lose the split capability. I am hoping there is a CSS only solution.

The result should be two aligned columns which are able to split when necessary, as shown in the picture link.

Comment: I don't think what you want to achieve is possible only with css. Either you need to make your layout column based (which will prevent you from having split functionality) or row based (in this case you won't have equal `div` widths without hard-coding, they'll simply adjust to size of their content). You'd be able to achieve this with js/jquery though, by detecting width of widest `div`, and applying same to rest of them. How open you are to js solution?

Comment: js sounds good to me. I sort of guessed that might be the case but was hoping there might be some kind of CSS calc() solution now available.

Comment: I can't think of any way, calc() could help here, but I do not know every possible css hack. JS is most probably the way here. Are you using jQuery in your setup?

Comment: No, there is currently no scripting at all.

Comment: Try this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/xz7y3aLf/7/ and let me know if this suits you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since I don't think it is possible with only CSS, I have a jQuery solution, so it goes:

```js
var xyz = $('.row div:first-child'),
  abc = $('.row div:nth-child(2n)'),
  arr = [],
  arr2 = [];

xyz.each(function() {
  arr.push($(this).width());
});

var max = Math.max.apply(Math, arr);
xyz.css('width', max);

abc.each(function() {
  arr2.push($(this).width());
});

var max2 = Math.max.apply(Math, arr2);
abc.css('width', max2);
```

```css
.row {
  width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.row div {
  float: left;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  margin: 1px;
}

.row div:nth-child(2) {
  margin-left: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="xyz">
  <div class="row">
    <div>The</div>
    <div>12</div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div>The cat</div>
    <div>12 34</div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div>The cat sat</div>
    <div>12 34 56</div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div>The cat sat on</div>
    <div>12 34 56 78</div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div>The cat sat on the</div>
    <div>12 34 56 78 9A</div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div>The cat sat on the mat</div>
    <div>12 34 56 78 9A BC</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Add to the second one `div` `margin-left` and `float: left`.

```
div div:nth-of-type(2) {float:left; border: 1px solid #ccc; margin: 1px 1px 1px 80px; width: 130px;}
                              ^^^^                                              ^^^^
```

https://jsfiddle.net/shhdq5kg/

Comment: Thank you, my aim is to have a simple two column aligned table style layout which is able to split at the column break when the browser width is reduced. This will help with mobile device layout. As the data being displayed changes, I am not able to hard code the widths.